# Changing opacity not working with JS and SVG in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm building a simple map, and need the correct svg direction line to display on input, while any other direction lines present fade away. This code is working in Firefox, though not in Chrome or Safari. Does webkit have a different way of handling this? Thanks for the help!

Javascript:

```
function getDirBut(){
        var input = $('.roomname').html();
        $('.direction').each(function(){
            var i = this;
            if($(i).attr('id') != ("d" + input) && $(i).attr('id') != undefined){
                $(i).css("transition","0.8s ease all");
                $(i).css('opacity',0);
            }else if($(i).attr('id') == ("d" + input)){
                $(i).css("transition","0.8s ease all");
                $(i).css('opacity',1);
            }
         });    
  }
```

Comment: Not sure about how this works with jQuery but it might be what's interfering. In any case, you can poke around to see how jQuery handles svg stuff internally - might even find compability tables, polyfills or a plugin that fixes incompatibilities. Also, this might help you check out for yourself: http://tests.caniuse.com/ - it uses modernizr to see if your browser supports stuff - it might make the details clearer. Using [caniuse](http://caniuse.com) directly would also be a good idea if you haven't checked it already.

Comment: try "-webkit-transition"

Answer (score 0):

You could try to target the opacity attribute of the svg instead of the CSS.

in native JS, this works on a svg path in Safari:

```
localSvgDoc.getElementById('myId').setAttribute('opacity', 0.3)
```